# Using array inside alignat to create equation legend

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, arrays

I want to describe the parameters in used in the equation in two columns below the equations. Something like this

```
**** = *******
*** = **********

  -                               -
 |   A: something                |  D: something
-|   B: something               -|  E: something
 |   C: smething                 |  F: something
  -                               -
```

Using `array` inside `alignat`, the following output is produced

```
\begin{figure} \label{eq1}
\tiny
\begin{alignat}{2}
   & E_{\mathrm{access}}    \mathord{=} E_{\mathrm{read}} \mathord{+} E_{\mathrm{write}} = E_{\mathrm{R\_L1}} \mathord{+} E_{\mathrm{R\_lower}} \mathord{+} E_{\mathrm{W\_L1}} \mathord{+} E_{\mathrm{W\_lower}} \label{equation1} \\
   .... \\
\begin{array}{l l}
   &h_{r1},h_{w1}: &  \text{Read,Write hits in L1}  \\ 
   &h_{r2},h_{w2}: &  \text{Read,Write hits in local L2} \\
   &h_{r3},h_{w3}: &  \text{Read,Write hits in peer L2} \\
   &h_{r4},h_{w4}: &  \text{Read,Write hits in memory} \\
   &E_{1}:         &  \text{Energy per access at L1} \\
   &E_{2}:         &  \text{Energy per access at L2 slice} \\
   &E_{d}:         &  \text{Energy per access at directory} \\
   &E_{r}:         &  \text{Energy per access at router} \\
   &E_{m}:         &  \text{Energy per access at memory} \\
   &E_{N}:         &  \text{Number of hops} \\
   &E_{i}(\mathrm{T}):         &  \text{Energy of tag array} \\
   &E_{i}(\mathrm{T,D}):         &  \text{Aggregate energy of tag and data arrays} \\
\end{array}   
\end{alignat}   
\end{figure}
```

[image]

The weird thing is that the equations are pushed to the right and that is because I used `\\` in the last equation. The equations are lengthy, so I didn't paste them.

Additionally, how can I create two column legend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `array` from the aligned portion and set it as a regular math element. Since you're in a `figure`, it should be centered by default making it look like a math display:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{align}
     f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c
  \end{align}

  $\begin{array}{l l}
     h_{r1},h_{w1}:       & \text{Read,Write hits in L1}  \\ 
     h_{r2},h_{w2}:       & \text{Read,Write hits in local L2} \\
     h_{r3},h_{w3}:       & \text{Read,Write hits in peer L2} \\
     h_{r4},h_{w4}:       & \text{Read,Write hits in memory} \\
     E_{1}:               & \text{Energy per access at L1} \\
     E_{2}:               & \text{Energy per access at L2 slice} \\
     E_{d}:               & \text{Energy per access at directory} \\
     E_{r}:               & \text{Energy per access at router} \\
     E_{m}:               & \text{Energy per access at memory} \\
     E_{N}:               & \text{Number of hops} \\
     E_{i}(\mathrm{T}):   & \text{Energy of tag array} \\
     E_{i}(\mathrm{T,D}): & \text{Aggregate energy of tag and data arrays} \\
  \end{array}$
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

You may also consider using an `array` column specification `l @{\ :\ } l` to set the `:` automatically. Expected output would be

[image]

---

Due to your thin columns, you won't be able to split the `array` into multiple side-be-side columns. However, this is how you can do that independent of the align construction:

```
%...
  $\begin{array}{l @{\ :\ } l}
     h_{r1},h_{w1}       & \text{Read,Write hits in L1}  \\ 
     h_{r2},h_{w2}       & \text{Read,Write hits in local L2} \\
     h_{r3},h_{w3}       & \text{Read,Write hits in peer L2} \\
     h_{r4},h_{w4}       & \text{Read,Write hits in memory} \\
     E_{1}               & \text{Energy per access at L1} \\
     E_{2}               & \text{Energy per access at L2 slice}
  \end{array}\quad
  \begin{array}{l @{\ :\ } l}
     E_{d}               & \text{Energy per access at directory} \\
     E_{r}               & \text{Energy per access at router} \\
     E_{m}               & \text{Energy per access at memory} \\
     E_{N}               & \text{Number of hops} \\
     E_{i}(\mathrm{T})   & \text{Energy of tag array} \\
     E_{i}(\mathrm{T,D}) & \text{Aggregate energy of tag and data arrays}
  \end{array}$
%...
```

`\quad` ensures a gap between the left/right portions of the `array`s. Here is the too-wide output:

[image]